Black spots on soldered joints
When I solder, I often end up with black spots like the ones you see in the picture. I circled one.

Is it burned flux? Will that affect the connections? How to avoid them?

Probably burnt flux.  Lowering the iron temperature might help if you're running really hot.  Usually though it will not hurt and aside from special fluxes it is not necessary to remove them.

You can also use 99% isopropyl alcohol and an old toothbrush to clean up the burned flux if that is the case. Only takes wetting the corner of the toothbrush and a quick scrub to clean up the joints (and rest of the PCB). It will flash-off a few seconds later. You can dry/polish with soft cotton cloth afterwards if you like. I'm not convinced that your temp is too high. Almost the opposite. If you are removing the solder-wire before the heat and you are still getting those tails, your temp may be low. For lead solder I've found (520 F/270 C) works nicely for most with .8mm solder.

Cleaning with isopropyl alcohol may help.

@DavidC.Rankin Keep in mind however that old toothbrushes (I've used them too, I'll admit) are not ESD proof and can cause ESD build-up. Using one might damage sensitive components. There are ESD brushes for this very purpose.

@Lundin chuckling... you of course are correct. I'll admit, I've yet to purchase any ESD brushes, but that has the caveat that I don't really have any horribly ESD sensitive components the ratty old toothbrush could kill (at least not near sea-level in a relatively humid environment). The usual culprit is that momentary lapse in thoughtfulness as the stray breadboard jumper slips and swings across a selection of ICs hitting all the wrong pins along the way... Experience is often the best teacher for thoughtfulness :)

Using a toothbrush and some isopropyl alcohol to brush the solder should help. It probably is just burnt flux.  Of course, unless you're displaying your PCB in an art museum, you don't need to do that as it does not affect the connection.
